# How can I ignore null values when iterating through a table (Javascript only)

Tags: javascript

I am iterating through a table using a for loop in Javascript.

Some cells have an approve/ignore drop down menu in them, but some don't
(some are blank, which was unfortunately part of the spec).
When it gets to a null value, the code falls over.

How can I get it to skip/ignore any null values?

```js
function submitform() {
    document.getElementById("nodata").className = "center form-message form- 
    message-warning hidden";
    document.getElementById("novehicle").className = "center form- 
    message form-message-warning hidden";
    selectTable = document.getElementById('despatchTable');
    rowLength = selectTable.rows.length;
    var vehicleError = 'N';
    var despatchData = "";  

    for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++){  // 
        if (null) {
            i++;
        }

        var selectCells = selectTable.rows.item(i).cells;
        var loadin = selectCells.item(0).innerHTML;
        var fieldout = " ";
        var loadVal = fillfield(loadin, 7, fieldout);
        var clientin = selectCells.item(3).innerHTML;                    
        fieldout = " ";
        var clientVal = fillfield(clientin, 8, fieldout); 
        var approvein = selectCells.item(6).children.approval.value;
        var approveVal = fillfield(approvein, 7, fieldout);
        var vehicleIn = selectCells.item(1).innerHTML;
        var vehicleLength = vehicleIn.trim().length;
    }       
}
```

The error message I get is

> Cannot read property 'children' of null' when item(6) equals null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it happens on this line
`var approvein = selectCells.item(6).children.approval.value;`

So before doing this you can test `if (selectCells.item(6)) {...`

Also, you have `if (null) { i++; }`. It will never be executed.
Maybe this is the place where you want to put the check.
And instead of incrementing `i`, it is better to `continue`.

Comment: Ah ok. I've just tried it and it works! I haven't used the 'continue' command before(like i say, i'm a noob). Thank you so much!